# What is the W_{variablename} variable in GeoDa's spatial lag model?

Tags: regression, geographically-weighted-regression, geoda

What is the W_{variablename} variable in GeoDa's spatial lag model output?

The geoda [workbook](http://www.csiss.org/clearinghouse/GeoDa/geodaworkbook.pdf) does not give any explanation.
As far as my knowledge goes a spatial lag regression model does not need an additional independent variable.

[image: Model output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I found the answer.

The following formula is used for the spatially lagged regression:

[image: Spatially lagged regression]

The W_PCTBACH and its coefficient refer to the first term (rho Wy).